# Variable in regexp expression used in TCL script does not match

Tags: regex, variables, tcl

The below code snippet fetches the **agent** container ID from the docket host and matches it with the container ID obtained on logging into **agent** container. 
This was written to validate if the agent container login is successful

```
   set var_op1 [VIR-APP exec "docker ps -aqf \"name=agent\""]

   set docker_op [VIR-APP exec "docker exec -it agent /bin/bash"]

   set var_op2 [VIR-APP exec "uname -a"]

   set result [regexp -nocase ".*$var_op1.*" $var_op2 match]
```

The regular expression i put is not matching.Could someone help?

Comment: Do you have an example of what sort of value it is looking for?

Comment: Sample output: var_op1 is 123 var_op2 is abc11 123 xyz22. Now i want to check if var_op2 contains var_op1 and pass if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can check for if a string is inside another string more simply with the `string first` command:

```
if {[string first $var_op1 $var_op2] >= 0} {
    # The $var_op1 string was found inside $var_op2
}
```

*However* you might find that this fails because the result of retrieving the value in `var_op1` contains extra whitespace (e.g., a trailing newline character). Because of that, you probably want to actually do:

```
if {[string first [string trim $var_op1] $var_op2] >= 0} {
    # The $var_op1 string was found inside $var_op2
}
```

(I believe that this is what is causing you problems with the `regexp` search, but any additional metadata characters would also cause problems; it's better to use `string first` here. Failing that, there's also `string match`, which uses glob-style matching such as most people are familiar with from filename handling, but that's a less correct tool right here.)

Comment: I tried all the above solution.still facing the same issue :(

Comment: Hi Donal, I guess its an issue with ats framework that i am using. I ran the script independently and it worked. Thanks a lot